# Pipe subprocess standard output to a variable

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, python-2.6

I want to run a command in `pythong`, using the subprocess module, and store the output in a variable. However, I do not want the command's output to be printed to the terminal.
For this code:

```
def storels():
   a = subprocess.Popen("ls",shell=True)
storels()
```

I get the directory listing in the terminal, instead of having it stored in `a`. I've also tried:

```
 def storels():
       subprocess.Popen("ls > tmp",shell=True)
       a = open("./tmp")
       [Rest of Code]
 storels()
```

This also prints the output of ls to my terminal. I've even tried this command with the somewhat dated os.system method, since running `ls > tmp` in the terminal doesn't print `ls` to the terminal at all, but stores it in `tmp`. However, the same thing happens.

**Edit:**

I get the following error after following marcog's advice, but only when running a more complex command. `cdrecord --help`. Python spits this out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./install.py", line 52, in <module>
    burntrack2("hi")
  File "./install.py", line 46, in burntrack2
    a = subprocess.Popen("cdrecord --help",stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just a note, using `shell=true` is discouraged in the Python docs. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: Use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75175057/12780274`

Comment: At least I know I'm not the only one who types Pythong now and then...

Answer (score 165, accepted):

To get the output of `ls`, use [`stdout=subprocess.PIPE`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE).

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = proc.stdout.read()
>>> print output
bar
baz
foo
```

The command `cdrecord --help` outputs to stderr, so you need to pipe that indstead. You should also break up the command into a list of tokens as I've done below, or the alternative is to pass the `shell=True` argument but this fires up a fully-blown shell which can be dangerous if you don't control the contents of the command string.

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['cdrecord', '--help'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = proc.stderr.read()
>>> print output
Usage: wodim [options] track1...trackn
Options:
    -version    print version information and exit
    dev=target  SCSI target to use as CD/DVD-Recorder
    gracetime=# set the grace time before starting to write to #.
...
```

If you have a command that outputs to both stdout and stderr and you want to merge them, you can do that by piping stderr to stdout and then catching stdout.

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

As mentioned by [Chris Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable/4514905#4514905), you should be using `proc.communicate()` instead of `proc.read()`.

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['cdrecord', '--help'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = proc.communicate()
>>> print 'stdout:', out
stdout: 
>>> print 'stderr:', err
stderr:Usage: wodim [options] track1...trackn
Options:
    -version    print version information and exit
    dev=target  SCSI target to use as CD/DVD-Recorder
    gracetime=# set the grace time before starting to write to #.
...
```

Comment: Alright, that works for 'ls', but later on I ran into a different problem, when trying to run a different command. When I try to run "cdrecord --help" with that method, I get a traceback error.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! That did it. If you don't mind me asking, how would you differentiate between using the stdout method and this stderr method?

Comment: @Insomaniacal In this case, I knew usage is generally dumped to stderr. But in general, a simple test is to `cmd > /dev/null` if you still see output it's going to stderr. Confirm by piping stderr `cmd 2> /dev/null` and it should vanish into `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Insomaniacal: in general `stdout` will be used, sometimes but sometimes `stderr`; in general, use `stdout` unless it doesn't work and then try `stderr`. I believe it can be arranged in some terminals to colour stderr differently so you can obviously tell.

Comment: or you can just do `subprocess.Popen(['cdrecord', '--help'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` to get them combined. Don't use `shell=True`, no reason for that.

Comment: @Forrest Edited that bit in. I removed `shell=True` in the process of incorporating Chris' answer.

Comment: Under Python3, `output` won't be a string, but a bytes sequence. Try `output.decode(encoding='utf-8')` or `output.decode(encoding='latin-1')` to obtain a string.

Comment: So why is this better than the below answer?

Comment: @swade After trying both, I learned it's because this answer allows you to capture and suppress both the stdout and stderr. Some programs output to one or the other or both. I was unable to get the below answer to suppress output.

Answer (score 49):

If you are using python 2.7 or later, the easiest way to do this is to use the [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) command.  Here is an example:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('ls')
```

To also redirect stderr you can use the following:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('ls', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

In the case that you want to pass parameters to the command, you can either use a list or use invoke a shell and use a single string.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-a'])
output = subprocess.check_output('ls -a', shell=True)
```

Comment: This does not suppress output, as requested ("I do not want the command's output to be printed to the terminal").

Comment: This does suppress all output to the terminal for me (as long as I use the stderr=subprocess.STDOUT to capture both STDOUT and STDERR).  Do you have an example command where it does not work?

Comment: Emre, I have seen this behavior with python 2.6

Comment: This also does not suppress output for me (using Python 3.9 and running an OpenSSL command)

Answer (score 16):

With `a = subprocess.Popen("cdrecord --help",stdout = subprocess.PIPE)`
, you need to either use a list or use `shell=True`;

Either of these will work.  The former is preferable.

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['cdrecord', '--help'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

a = subprocess.Popen('cdrecord --help', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Also, instead of using `Popen.stdout.read`/`Popen.stderr.read`, you should use `.communicate()` (refer to the subprocess documentation for why).

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cdrecord', '--help'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```