# How to redirect system call output to a string

Tags: python, unix, system-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pipe subprocess standard output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable)

I am running a python program :

```
import os
os.system("ls") # ls command runs on the terminal
```

To store the output in a file :

```
os.system("ls > a.txt")
```

What I need is, it stores the output in some temporary string . IS THAT POSSIBLE ??

Comment: No. You can't do that. Read the content of a.txt into a variable after the system call. Better yet use python pipes.

Comment: @SridharJagannathan You are wrong. Of course you can do that, using the subprocess module of python.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus I did mention pipes.

Answer (score 5):

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()[0]
```

Here you run the external command `ls` and redirects both the `stderr` and `stdout` strewams of the command to the variable `output`.

Where the streams have to be redirected are specified using the arguments `stdout` and `stderr` of the `Popen` function.