# Capturing output of valgrind into programming

Tags: c, testing, memory-leaks, valgrind, perl-module

I want to test a C code under valgrind with different option. And I want to be able to capture all the outputs and report test success/fail depending on the result of those runs. Initially I thought of perl module **Test::Valgrind** but was not able to use it. Is there any other option to do this?

Comment: "*... but was not able to use it.*" If this is the problem, you should tag this question [perl], but [c] and tell us more about it.

Comment: my question is if there are any other ways to fetch valgrind output into code written in any programming language.

Comment: do you mean using python script?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all available languages provide means of capturing output of external program runs.

- C: `popen`, `pclose` - pipe stream to or from a process
- Perl: backticks (``) operator or `open` function - [executing external commands](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands)
- Python: see [Pipe subprocess standard output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable)