# In python, subprocess call using string values

Tags: python

I want to call c program from python. My c program required several input arguments (for calculating several properties of image) for example, image name, central position (x_c, y_c), area, radii etc. So these input arguments I am calculating in python and then want to pass it to the c program. In python code, I need to first get image for which I need to calculate x_c, y_c, area etc. So in python script I used,

```
file=sys.argv[1] # here I am passing the name of input image
***
calculate x_c, y_c, area, etc...
***
```

Now in the same python script, I want to pass above calculated values as well as image name to the c program. In python, image name is in string and calculated values are in float, so how can I pass all to the c program using `subprocess call` or `os.system`?
So far I tried,

```
os.system("cshift "+str(file)+' '+str(x_c) +' '+str(y_c)+' '+str(area))
```

but its not giving me the proper answer.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

-Viral

Comment: I just realize (after writing my answer), what do you mean by "it's not giving me the proper answer" ?

Comment: It means, without calculating properties, c program was giving just zero value. C program was not taking arguments properly. Now it works with your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.system) documentation:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function.

So `subprocess.call(['cshift', str(file), str(x_c), str(y_c), str(area)])` should do the trick.

If you want to read the output of your C code, you have to use a [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) object with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['cshift', str(file), str(x_c), str(y_c), str(area)], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.stdout.read()
```

On a side note, I recommend you to take a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html) or [`begins`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/begins/0.9) to handle the arguments of your python script.

**Related question:**

- [pipe subprocess standard output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I store values from this C code output? Simply  `results=subprocess.call...' is not saving values in results.