# Read results from terminal command without saving to a file first in python

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system, system

Good evening/morning,

I have been passing a lot of commands to the terminal in a python program and was wondering if there was a way of passing a command and immediately saving the printed information without having to first save it to a file and then read that file in?

For example, this is what I have been doing:

```
os.system("lspci -tv > results")
if Addresses[i-1] in open('results').read():
```

Is there a way to just store the results from lspci -tv to a variable in my program so my program isn't dependent on another file and cluttering my computer with files every time I need to use this method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, according with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable):

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()

print output
```

Or if you want an array with the results:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()
array = output.split("\n")[:-1]

for i in range(len(array)):
    print str(i) + " : " + array[i]
```

Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#).

Comment: I've come across this before and used it, although the functionality seems limited. If, for example I want to execute: "lspci -vvv" or "lspci -tv" as I mentioned, it throws an error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdout.py", line 3, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen('lspci -tv', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Try adding shell=True before stdout=subprocess.PIPE (looks the edit)

Comment: Thankyou, that did the trick. You saved me a lot of time poking around for this as there are so many variations of this code.