# handling exit status popen python

Tags: python

I am tring to handle status exit with popen but it gives a error, the code is:

```
import os
try:
    res = os.popen("ping -c 4 www.google.com")
except IOError:
    print "ISPerror: popen"
try:
    #wait = [0,0]
    wait = os.wait()
except IOError:
    print "ISPerror:os.wait"

if wait[1] != 0:
    print("  os.wait:exit status != 0\n")
else:
    print ("os.wait:"+str(wait))
print("before read")
result = res.read()

print ("after read:")

print ("exiting")
```

But it if giving the following error:

close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 10] No child processes

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

Answer (score 3):

## Error Explanation

It looks like this error is occurring because upon exiting, the program tries to destroy `res`, which involves calling the `res.close()` method. But somehow  invoking `os.wait()` has already closed the object. So it's trying to close `res` twice, resulting in the error. If the call to `os.wait()` is removed, the error no longer occurs.

```
import os
try:
    res = os.popen("ping -c 4 www.google.com")
except IOError:
    print "ISPerror: popen"

print("before read")
result = res.read()
res.close() # explicitly close the object
print ("after read: {}".format(result)

print ("exiting")
```

But this leaves you with the problem of knowing when the process has finished. And since `res` just has type `file`, your options are limited. I would instead move to using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3)

## Using subprocess.Popen

To use `subprocess.Popen`, you pass your command in as a `list` of strings. To be able to [access the output of the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable), you set the `stdout` argument to `subprocess.PIPE`, which allows you to access `stdout` later on using file operations. Then, instead of using the regular `os.wait()` method, `subprocess.Popen` objects have their own `wait` methods you call directly on the object, this also [sets the `returncode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method) value which represents the exit status.

```
import os
import subprocess

# list of strings representing the command
args = ['ping', '-c', '4', 'www.google.com']

try:
    # stdout = subprocess.PIPE lets you redirect the output
    res = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
except OSError:
    print "error: popen"
    exit(-1) # if the subprocess call failed, there's not much point in continuing

res.wait() # wait for process to finish; this also sets the returncode variable inside 'res'
if res.returncode != 0:
    print("  os.wait:exit status != 0\n")
else:
    print ("os.wait:({},{})".format(res.pid, res.returncode)

# access the output from stdout
result = res.stdout.read()
print ("after read: {}".format(result))

print ("exiting")
```