# proper way to check exit codes python3

Tags: python, exit-code

I have a var `exitcd` that executes a command. Its supposed to get  the `exit code` of running the command and then fall into one of the if/elif conditions based on that exit code.

However, it is failing stating `general error occurred` when the `-d` being used is telling me it should be hitting `elif exitcd == 3` but that is not occurring.

```
exitcd=os.popen('cmd test ').read()
print(exitcd)
#print("retcode was {}".format(retcode))
#not found
if exitcd == 0:
    continue
# found
elif exitcd == 1:
    subprocess.Popen('cmd test -d --insecure --all-projects --json >> a_dir_res_storage')
    subprocess.Popen('cmd monitor --all-projects')
    continue
#error with command
elif exitcd == 2:
    print('error with command')
    continue
#failure to find project manifest
elif exitcd == 3:
    print('error with find manifests for {}'.format(storage+'/'+a_dir))
    continue
else:
    print('general error occurred.')
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [handling exit status popen python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689014/handling-exit-status-popen-python)

Comment: The result of `os.popen(...).read()` is not an exit code.  It is the `stdout` content from the command.

Comment: You don't have a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super crude example of how I've typically run external commands from Python.  Using the `communicate` method not only allows you to get the return code from the command, but the output sent to `stdout` and `stderr` are independent.

```
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 #
 cmd_fails = ["/bin/false"]
 run_fails = Popen(cmd_fails, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
 out, err = run_fails.communicate()
 rc = run_fails.returncode
 print(f"out:{out}\nerr:{err}\nrc={rc}")
 #     
 cmd_works = ["/bin/echo", "Hello World!"]
 run_works = Popen(cmd_works, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
 out, err = run_works.communicate()
 rc = run_works.returncode
 print(f"out:{out}\nerr:{err}\nrc={rc}")
```