# How do I send an variable to a blender python script?

Tags: python, variables, attributes, blender

I have script1, in there the String "path" gets set. Then the script1 runs blender as a subprocess, together with script2.
Now script2 needs to have access to the String "path", how can I do this?

Currently im Saving the string to a text file and then accesing it from script2 but I know this solution is very very ugly.

maybe someone has an idea ? :)

script1:

```
path=("/example/ex/")
subprocess.run([blenderpath, "--background", blenderscene, "--python", scriptpath])
```

script2 (atm just reading out the txt file with the right path, but that's not how I want it to be):

```
file=open("Blabla")
file_name = fiel.readline()
mat_path = file_name

def prepscene(mat_path)
```

It works right now with the text file, but If I try to import the variable into the second script it won't work, if I try to somehow start the blender script with it it also won't work.

Comment: Please add some code, then it will be easier to help.

Comment: sorry its my first time using stack overflow, maybe this edit helps

Comment: you want to pass a value to the second file ?

Comment: You could try setting an environment variable.

Comment: You can read output from subprocess module like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514776/7837680 Using this you can print variable in one script and read it in another.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys       # to get command line args

argv = sys.argv
argv will be array
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the varible you can use importing.

ScriptA:

```
...
path = "/example/ex/"
...
```

ScriptB:

```
from .ScriptA import path
```

(this only works if both scripts are in the same directory)